# Arduino Wire.h send double to lcd

Tags: programming, lcd, wire-library

I'd like the double number 200.00 shown as `200.00` on my LCD screen.

For instance, when I pass just a number (`int`) like 40 to the LCD, it uses it as an ASCII code to show a character on the display.

Now I want to send a `double` to it and it should be displayed as a double.

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
   Wire.begin(0x63);
}


double f;
void loop() {

  f = 200.00;

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x63);
  Wire.write(byte(0x00));
  Wire.write(4); //HIDE CURSOR
  Wire.write(12); //CLEAR SCREEN
  Wire.write(13); //CURSOR 2nd LINE
  Wire.write("Frequenz: ");
  Wire.write(f); //<- How to do this?
  Wire.write("Hz");
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino [Wire](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire) class does only support [write()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireWrite) of byte, string and vector of bytes. To write a double it must first be converted to a string. This can be done with the standard C library function [dtostrf()](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html).

```
double f;

void loop() {
  char buf[10];

  f = 200.00;

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x63);
  Wire.write(byte(0x00));
  Wire.write(4); //HIDE CURSOR
  Wire.write(12); //CLEAR SCREEN
  Wire.write(13); //CURSOR 2nd LINE
  Wire.write("Frequenz: ");
  Wire.write(dtostrf(f, 0, 2, buf));
  Wire.write("Hz");
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

The class inherits from [Print](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.h) (via [Stream](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stream)) so that the overloaded member function [print()](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.h#L67) for double can be used. In that case:

```
double f;

void loop() {
  f = 200.00;

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x63);
  Wire.write(byte(0x00));
  Wire.write(4); //HIDE CURSOR
  Wire.write(12); //CLEAR SCREEN
  Wire.write(13); //CURSOR 2nd LINE
  Wire.write("Frequenz: ");
  Wire.print(f);
  Wire.write("Hz");
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

Please note that the maximum number of bytes to write (between beginTransmission and endTransmission) is [limited to 32](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h#L28) in the standard configuration of the Arduino core.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Wire.print()`, instead of `Wire.write()` which is intended only to output single bytes or byte arrays.